# Can't get my Stack Overflow CV to print to PDF nicely

Tags: support, developer-story, cv-export

Both views look good in the browser:

- https://stackoverflow.com/cv/k06a
- https://stackoverflow.com/story/k06a

Until I try to print it to PDF - it seems very poorly formatted.

Is there any chance I can get a CV of normal quality?

[image]

Comment: Why not use the *save as PDF* option on your *developer story* tab?

Comment: BTW neither link (for me) shows your email address and phone number - is that expected?

Comment: @WaiHaLee yep, this info is public

Answer (score 16):

Your CV can be saved as PDF from your *Developer Story* tab:

> [image: Circled *Save as PDF* button on the right-hand side of the Developer Story tab, with *The PDF uses a traditional view* tooltip visible]

The resulting CV is very nicely laid out:

[image: Screenshot of CV PDF, contact details blurred out]

Comment: Thanks, it is much better, but images are missing :(

Comment: @k06a: that could make a nice, new feature request.

Answer (score -9):

I just discovered a way to save a PDF with the original website content from iOS Safari:

```
Create PDF
```

[image]